# Filter by date in date control

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
$filter .="<option value='ALL' selected=selected> All Months  - [" . $allcnt . "]  </option>";

$query = "select LockerInfo_IDNo, ExpiryDate, count(LockerInfo_IDNo) count1 from lockerinfo  
          WHERE ExpiryDate<>'' 
          group by MONTH(ExpiryDate) 
          order by ExpiryDate ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('101. Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if($mnt==date("d-m-Y",$row['ExpiryDate']))
        $filter .="<option value='" . $row['ExpiryDate'] . "' selected=selected> " . $space1 . date("M",$row['ExpiryDate']) . " - [" . $row['count1'] . "]</option>";
    else
        $filter .="<option value='" . $row['ExpiryDate'] . "'> " . $space1 . date("M",$row['ExpiryDate']) . " - [" . $row['count1'] . "]</option>";
}


$filter .=" </select>";
echo $filter;
```

This was my query in this listbox values should b group by month...if use this query means its showing only 2 records ...but I have 535 values in db...help me

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: i want show a month only once per year?

Comment: _“bt am havin 535 values in db”_ – with how many _different_ month values? Sounds like you don’t really now what GROUP BY does …

Comment: Are you sure that there are any records related to more than 2 months in your db ?

Comment: I'd recommend rewriting this code because it has several problems: 1. Deprecated database API is used. 2. Three layers (presentation logic, data access logic and business logic) are mixed up. 3. HTML is inlined in php code that makes graphical changes PITA.

Comment: yes...jan having 36,and feb 28 and etc...but may and jun in both 2013 and 2014....

Comment: @Leri its not even showing 12 month it shows only 2 months may and june....

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite query and see what in results:

```
      select YEAR(ExpiryDate) as expireYear, MONTH(ExpiryDate) as expireMonth, count(LockerInfo_IDNo) count1 
      from lockerinfo  
      WHERE ExpiryDate<>'' 
      group by YEAR(ExpiryDate) , MONTH(ExpiryDate) 
      order by 1, 2
```

PHP script for example:

```
$resultSet = [];
/* uncomment to use real data 
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
          $resultSet[] = $row;
 */
// Example data start
$resultSet[] = ['expireYear' => '2013', 'expireMonth' => '01', 'count1' => 12]; 
$resultSet[] = ['expireYear' => '2013', 'expireMonth' => '05', 'count1' => 20]; 
$resultSet[] = ['expireYear' => '2013', 'expireMonth' => '11', 'count1' => 30]; 
// Example data end 
$currentMonth = date('Ym'); 
$space1 = "  ";
foreach ($resultSet as $row ){
   $ym = $row['expireYear'].$row['expireMonth'];
   $text = date("Y M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['expireMonth'], 1, $row['expireYear'])) . " - [".$row['count1']."]";
   $filter .= "<option value='{$ym}' ".($currentMonth == $ym ? 'selected' : '')."> " . $space1 .  $text . "</option>";
}
echo "<select>".$filter."</select>";
```

Comment: i want to show every month in tat listbox which are in d field...for example jan 2013 having 29 entries ,may having 20 entries it sholud it should disply only once in that list box..

Comment: You should have in results from database rows with data like: "`'2013', '01', 12`", "`'2013', '05', 20`", correct?

Comment: thank u...this was d mistake group by from_unixtime(ExpiryDate, '%Y%m')